# toggle what an iframe displays

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe

I have an iframe on my webpage, now I want 2 buttons above this iframe which will change what is being displayed in that iframe.

So it remains only one iframe always showing, but one button makes it one url then the other button changes it to another url.

How would this be done, Thank you.

Comment: Javascript is your friend, bind click event on buttons and change iframe src on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="load('page1.html')" value="page 1"/>
<input type="button" onclick="load('page2.html')" value="page 2"/>

<iframe id="my_iframe"></iframe> 

<script>
function load(page) {
  document.getElementById("my_iframe").src = page;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up **event listeners** on the `button`s to listen for a `click` event. Inside the event, determine which button was `click`ed and change the `src` attribute of your `iframe` to the content you're wanting to show.

**HTML**

```
<button id="one">Test 1</button>
<button id="two">Test 2</button>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Zfq7v/" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("one");
var buttonTwo = document.getElementById("two");
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

buttonOne.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);
buttonTwo.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);

function buttonClick(e){
    if(e.target.id === "one"){
        iframe.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Zfq7v/";
    }else{
        iframe.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/u73rF/";
    } 
};
```

*Note: You could just as easily have two separate event functions and not just one `buttonClick` event`*

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/AvEqM/)